# How do I get the profile pic for the person who commented from the Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am modifying the code from the [Facebook Live comments teleprompter](https://github.com/fbsamples/live-comments-teleprompter).

I want to be able to display the profile pic as well as the name of the person commenting. Currently, the code only displays the name, taken from `comment.from.name`.

How do I get the profile pic of the commenter using the Facebook Graph API using the code below? I tried `comment.from.picture` but that doesn't work.

```
function refresh() {
        $countdown.removeAttr('value');
        lastReloadTime = null;

        return getLastLiveVideo().then(function(video) {
                // Merge video with comments and reactions
                return $.when(
                    getComments(video.id),
                    getReactions(video.id)
                ).then(function(comments, reactions) {
                    video.comments = comments;
                    video.reactions = reactions;
                    return video;
                });

            }).then(function(video) {
                    $('.comments').empty();
                    video.comments.forEach(function(comment) {
                        $('.comments').append(
                            $('<div class="comment"></div>').append(
                                $('<h2 class="name">').text(comment.from.name),
                                $('<p class="time"></p>').text(
                                    Math.floor(
                                        (new Date() - new Date(comment.created_time)) / 1000 / 60
                                    ) + ' min. ago'
                                ),
                                $('<p></p>').text(comment.message)
                            )
                        );
                    });
```

Comment: The data is fetch in getComments. So you would have to show that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer.

The url of the profile pic is in `comment.from.picture.data.url`

So the code is as follows:

```
function refresh() {
  $countdown.removeAttr('value');
  lastReloadTime = null;

  return getLastLiveVideo().then(function (video) {

    // Merge video with comments and reactions
    return $.when(
      getComments(video.id),
      getReactions(video.id)
    ).then(function (comments, reactions) {
      video.comments = comments;
      video.reactions = reactions;
      return video;
    });

  }).then(function (video) {
    $('.comments').empty();
    video.comments.forEach(function (comment) {
      $('.comments').append(
        $('<div class="comment"></div>').append(
          $('<h2 class="name">').html("<img src=\""+comment.from.picture.data.url+"\" class=\"fbprofilepic\"/>"+comment.from.name),
          $('<p class="time"></p>').text(
            Math.floor(
              (new Date() - new Date(comment.created_time)) / 1000 / 60
            ) + ' min. ago'
          ),
          $('<p></p>').text(comment.message)
        )
      );
    });
```